# iOS NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest incorrectly reports SSL certificate error for HTTPS sites

Tags: ios, xcode, http, nsurlconnection

The following iOS playground snippet:

```
import UIKit

// let urlPath = "http://ip.jsontest.com"
let urlPath = "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet"

var url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

var response: NSURLResponse?

var error: NSError?

var dataVal =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error:&error)

if error == nil {
    println(response)
} else {
    println(error)
}
```

Correctly prints the response for the HTTP url, but says that the HTTPS url has a certificate error.  I've tried three different sites that I know have valid certificates.  Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an iOS playground bug.  In an OSX playground, both URLs work, and both work in a real iOS app.  So, this is apparently just a playground issue.